# Output sorted in a weird way

Tags: c, sorting

I wrote below code but something is wrong as seen from the output.
I made a pointer mistake maybe. Can you help?

Unsorted Names:

Newyork
Georgia
Boston

Sorted Names:

Bostork
Georgia
Newyon

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 3

void sort(char x[3][100]);
void swap(char **, char **);

int i,j;
char names[SIZE][100];
char *temp;

int main(void){

//get the names of the cities
puts("Enter names of cities");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{       
    fgets( names[i], 99, stdin );
}
//print entered names
puts("\nUnsorted Names:\n");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%s", names[i]);
}

sort(names);

//print sorted names
puts("\nSorted Names:\n");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%s", names[i]);
}

getch();
 }

//sorting function
void sort(char angut[3][100]){

for (i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp( angut[i], angut[j] ) >0)
        {
            swap(&angut[i],&angut[j]);
        }

    }

}

}

  //swapping function
  void swap(char **first, char **second){

temp=*second;
*second=*first;
*first=temp;

}
```

Comment: I need Boston Georgia Newyork as output.

Comment: Are you joking or what? Not funny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in the realm of undefined behavior. Let's compile your code with a real compiler, such as gcc. This is the (relevant) output:

```
a.c: In function 'sort':
a.c:50:13: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
a.c:8:6: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'
a.c:50:13: warning: passing argument 2 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
a.c:8:6: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'
```

As you can see, you are giving bad arguments to `swap`. Why is that bad argument? Here's why:

`angut` is a 2d array, which in reality is just a single array that is divided in rows. `angut[i]` is a row of that array. Note that this is not a pointer, it's really the whole row of that array, of type `char [100]`. (Side note: If you pass it to a function, it **decays** to a pointer). Now you are taking its address, i.e., the address of a row in that array, which is of type `char (*)[100]`.

This is now a pointer that you are trying to pass to `swap`. But wait, this is not a pointer to a pointer (to char), it's a pointer to a row of an array. That's were the incompatibility comes from and that's why you get wrong results.

---

This should be enough of an answer to your problem, but here's what's happening underneath and hence the strange results. Let's look at a `char **`:

```
+----------+        +----------+        +----------+
| char **a |  ----> |  char *b |  ----> |  char c  |
+----------+        +----------+        +----------+
```

by changing `*a`, you are changing `b`. Now let's see what you have actually sent to that function:

```
+----------------+        +--------------+
| char (*a)[100] |  ----> |  char b[100] |
+----------------+        +--------------+
```

So now changing `*a` actually changes `b`, which is your data, not pointer to your data. The `swap` function doesn't know that, so it thinks `a` is a `char **`. So what `swap` thinks `*a` means is a pointer to some string, right? What you are actually giving it is the string itself.

So when you do `*a1 = *a2;`, the compiler takes 4 bytes (in your architecture) from where `a2` points to and writes it to 4 bytes from `a1` points to.

Do you see what's happening? Basically, the first four bytes of your strings are being swapped, framed as pointers. That's why you see `Bostork` and `Newyon` where the first four characters are swapped.

Answer (score 2):

Try using actual string copies in your swap function, would be inefficient, but work (instead of pointer assignment).

```
 void swap(char **first, char **second){

    char temp[100];
    strcpy(temp, *second);
    strcpy(*second, *first);
    strcpy(*first, temp);
}
```