# Why this code does what it does?

Tags: c, sorting

There's this recent question somebody posted. Here's the link:
[Output sorted in a weird way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984713/output-sorted-in-a-weird-way)

I know how it's wrong, but what I'm trying to figure out is, why it produces it's output the way it is?
After changing `getch()` to `getchar()` I compiled it and run a few times. It always changes `first 4 letters`. I can't see `where` this change actuallly takes place in the code.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have already [answered your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987583/912144) on the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens in the `swap` function:

```
//swapping function
void swap(char **first, char **second)
...
```

The OP assumed a 'char *' is an integral type, and moving it around would move *the string* around. Second part is that this swap function should accept *pointers* to data, not actual data. It swaps the *addresses* of the data and does not touch the data itself.

However, when called with `char * *`, it goes wrong. This swaps data at the address of 'a pointer to'. But the input was not "pointer to-pointer to".

'Pointer to' has a `sizeof int` on most systems (where 'most' is a subjective assessment -- search for "sizeof pointer" for discussions and opinions). So this routine swaps not a string *or* a pointer-to-string, it swaps the *integers* at the target addresses. Since an integer is, according to the result, 4 bytes long on the OP's machine, the code "swaps" the first four bytes of the target strings.

Comment: Now I see the 4 characters swap issue... I had seen it all but I forgot that `1 int == 4 chars` (compiler dependant).

Comment: It's so obvious now. I hate my "blackouts" as much as I hate not understanding something. Thanks.

Comment: @zubergu: no worries. For me, programming often comes down to "trial and error". If the trial fails, sometimes you spot the error right away, and sometimes you have to go over Every Single Line -- Twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change takes place in errant function `swap()` in OP post 
[Output sorted in a weird way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984713/output-sorted-in-a-weird-way)

```
char *temp;
...
void swap(char **first, char **second) {
  temp = *second;  // Copy 4-byte pointer
  *second = *first;// Copy 4-byte pointer
  *first = temp;   // Copy 4-byte pointer
}
```